# Using MVC 3 Validators, the sum Textbox one and Textbox 2 can not be greater than 100

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I only know simple MVC validation attributes. How could I do validation where the sum of two texbox fields cannot be greater than 100. I am sure this is probably an easy solution. I tried writing some code in  my controller but that was getting messy.

Comment: One way would be to create a custom validator.  Here's a [walkthrough](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301022/Creating-Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-MVC-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use client-side (javascript) event for validation.

For eg.:

**Using jQuery:**

```
$(function(){   
  $("#buttonID").on("click", function(event){
  if(parseInt($("#txtBox1").val()) + parseInt($("#txtBox2").val()) > 100)
  {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert("Value should be less than 100.");
  }
  });
});
```